# PHP fputcsv not appending all data in csv

Tags: php, file, csv, yii, fputcsv

I have this simple function to write data to csv, but not able to write all the data that I fetch.

Consider an example where I have 500 records to write to csv, which will correspond to 500 rows in csv. While I run this operation it sometimes write only 120 rows or 150 or even 10 rows . Everytime I run this function I get variable rows not 500 rows.

I have not yet found the root cause of why it not writing all 500 records that I fetch.

Following is the PHP code :

```
$arrHead = array();
            $arrHead = array('Assign to','Group assigned to','Customer name','Email','Phone','created Date','Ticket type',
                    'Ticket Status','internal note','Ticket number','Subject','Origin','Travel Start Date','Destination',
                    'Package Type','Lead Received','Mail box ID');

$csvfname   =   time().'.csv';



        if(Yii::app()->params['env'] == "LOCAL")
        {
            $basePath = '/var/www/c360/uploads/1/1/';
            $basePath = '/var/www/html/c360/uploads/1/1/'; //  Mangesh
        }
        else
        {
            $basePath = '/data/cview/run/nginx/htdocs/c360/uploads/1/1/';
        }

        $completeFilePath = $basePath . $csvfname;

       if (!empty($arrRecords) && count($aarrRecords) > 0)
        {

            $fp = fopen ($completeFilePath,'w+');
            fputcsv($fp, $arrHead,",",'"');
            chmod($completeFilePath, 0777);

            foreach ($arrRecords as $keyTicket => $arrTicket)
            {
                // preparing columns data into array
                $columnValue = array();
                $columnValue['col1'] =  trim('some value');
                .
                .
                .
                .

                // after the data is prepared in array I write it to CSV
                fputcsv($fp, $columnValue,",",'"');



            }
                fclose ($fp);
        }
```

After it writes to CSV , and when i check the CSV has less data appended, not all 500 rows

I dont know here I'm wrong in this case.

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL); to the top of your script. It looks like a memory issue or time limit error.

Comment: @BornKillaz - Nothing. Error Reporting gave me nothing.

Comment: @BornKillaz - also I have set the time limit of 10000 seconds .

Comment: check the size for memory_limit in php.ini

Comment: Do you have maybe set a limit somewhere (which is also saved in a session) and maybe automatically set to your search method in your ActiveRecord? I wonder why your output is always 10,120, 150. Are these numbers which you also use in some limit select field on your frontend application? Also check the sql queries which are done if everything is selected.